# xcodebuild with maximum-concurrent-test-simulator-destinations 1 hangup

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing

Im running UI and Unit tests of my app by xcodebuild with multiple destinations. And without concurrent testing it freezing after first destination. 
 The script is Fastlane lane

```
  desc "Run UI and Unit tests"
  lane :tests do

    xcodebuild = "xcodebuild \
    -workspace ../MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme \"Demo\" \
    -destination platform=iOS\\ Simulator,OS=11.4,name=iPhone\\ 8 \
    -destination platform=iOS\\ Simulator,name=iPhone\\ 11 \
    test \
    -maximum-concurrent-test-simulator-destinations 1"

    sh("set -o pipefail && #{xcodebuild} | xcpretty --color")

  end
```

maximum-concurrent-test-simulator-destinations set to one because Travis can't handle multiple simulators. With maximum-concurrent-test-simulator-destinations set 2 of higher it works fine(on my local machine)
Console output

```
[10:20:16]: ▸ 2020-05-12 10:20:16.524 xcodebuild[65456:1245746]  IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test session to:
[10:20:16]: ▸ /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hhnajatcmwzivkcbkmpbygtxpake/Logs/Test/Test-Demo-2020.05.12_10-20-11-+0300.xcresult/Staging/2_Test/Diagnostics/MyAppTests-FAE8B487-284C-40DB-B047-D636446674F3/MyAppTests-DE767895-6440-438A-870C-CC6B04A10DE0/Session-MyAppTests-2020-05-12_102016-h2zfGe.log
[10:20:16]: ▸ 2020-05-12 10:20:16.525 xcodebuild[65456:1245664] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (131BCBB5-8D86-4867-A62B-3D0B314D3D45) Beginning test session MyAppTests-131BCBB5-8D86-4867-A62B-3D0B314D3D45 at 2020-05-12 10:20:16.525 with Xcode 11E503a on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7fec47d23170> {
[10:20:16]: ▸ SimDevice: iPhone 8 (5F564306-1082-49FD-960C-C0F5ACC5B97D, iOS 11.4, Shutdown)
[10:20:16]: ▸ } (11.4 (15F79))
[10:20:17]: ▸ 2020-05-12 10:20:17.802 xcodebuild[65456:1245664] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (131BCBB5-8D86-4867-A62B-3D0B314D3D45) Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing.
[10:20:26]: ▸ 2020-05-12 10:20:26.027 xcodebuild[65456:1245735]  IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test session to:
[10:20:26]: ▸ /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hhnajatcmwzivkcbkmpbygtxpake/Logs/Test/Test-Demo-2020.05.12_10-20-11-+0300.xcresult/Staging/2_Test/Diagnostics/MyAppUITests-517BF762-E9D0-4897-A285-576F19851F35/MyAppUITests-9CAA0288-4B7A-46CC-892F-2B41A091D411/Session-MyAppUITests-2020-05-12_102026-JQAEh6.log
[10:20:26]: ▸ 2020-05-12 10:20:26.027 xcodebuild[65456:1245664] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (0D08CB0A-9292-48A4-AF86-C03EF96AABD0) Beginning test session MyAppUITests-0D08CB0A-9292-48A4-AF86-C03EF96AABD0 at 2020-05-12 10:20:26.027 with Xcode 11E503a on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7fec47d23170> {
[10:20:26]: ▸ SimDevice: iPhone 8 (5F564306-1082-49FD-960C-C0F5ACC5B97D, iOS 11.4, Booted)
[10:20:26]: ▸ } (11.4 (15F79))
[10:20:26]: ▸ 2020-05-12 10:20:26.034 xcodebuild[65456:1245664] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (0D08CB0A-9292-48A4-AF86-C03EF96AABD0) Finished requesting crash reports. Continuing with testing.
[10:20:45]: ▸ 2020-05-12 10:20:45.082 xcodebuild[65456:1245664] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 28.567 elapsed -- Testing started completed.
[10:20:45]: ▸ 2020-05-12 10:20:45.082 xcodebuild[65456:1245664] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.000 sec, +0.000 sec -- start
[10:20:45]: ▸ 2020-05-12 10:20:45.082 xcodebuild[65456:1245664] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 28.567 sec, +28.567 sec -- end
```

And it newer continues

Answer (score -2):

Solution was pritty obvious. 
You should set **parallel-testing-enabled NO** instead of **maximum-concurrent-test-simulator-destinations 1**

In my case parallel testing was disabled in xcode schema but it doesn't help. You have to set it to **xcodebuild**.